# Parse Query returning empty NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve all of the 'event' class PFObjects stored on my Parse database inside of my main ViewController's viewDidLoad method. This is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {    

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"event"];

        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *events, NSError *error){
            if (error){
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                [alertView show];
            } else {
                self.calendarTable = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                self.currentDay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                NSLog(@"%@", events);
                for (PFObject *event in events) {
                    NSLog(@"Test");
                    NSLog(@"%@", event[@"Time"]);
                    NSString *date = event[@"Time"];

                    if (self.calendarTable[date]){
                        [self.calendarTable[date] addObject:event];
                    } else {
                        self.calendarTable[date] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                        [self.calendarTable[date] addObject:event];
                    }
                }

                NSArray *keys = [self.calendarTable allKeys];
                self.cronKeys =  [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(NSString *d1, NSString *d2) {
                    NSDate *date1 = [NSDate dateFromString:d1];
                    NSDate *date2 = [NSDate dateFromString:d2];
                    return [date1 compare:date2];
                }];
                NSLog(@"%@", self.cronKeys);
                NSLog(@"%@", keys);
                [self.tableView reloadData];
                self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
            }
        }];
}
```

I've already double checked to make sure I have the right ApplicationID and Clientkey, and I'm not getting any errors when I run the app -- instead when I NSLog the array I'm getting back from the query, it's empty. I know for a fact that there are 14 'event' Parse objects existing on the database I'm trying to access.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!
~Psycode

Comment: are you sure your class name is not `Event` instead of `event`?

Comment: Yes, I checked that as well, the class name shows up as 'event' in the UI. Would that kind of problem not result in an error though?

Comment: I'm starting to think it has something to do with the setup of the connection to Parse, because upon creating a secondary test app with the sole purpose of accessing anything off of my Parse database, I couldn't access either the PFObjects stored under the key 'User' nor the key 'event'. @rob180

Answer (score 0):

Finally found my answer -- it didn't have anything to do with the code, as the code was perfectly sound with respect to connecting to Parse and retrieving data. The issue was somehow with the way the objects had been saved in the Parse database; once the objects had already been created, I made the mistake of going into the database via a web browser and changing one of the fields for every single one of the 14 objects. For some reason I don't quite understand, this caused the objects to be inaccessible.